# Git svn clone produces empty directory

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to clone the SVN repository at http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm when I do a `svn co http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm` it works fine but if I do a `git svn clone -s http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm` it produces an  produces a josm directory with nothing but a .git directory in it. Is there something I'm missing? Here's the output of the command:

```
$ git svn clone -s http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm
WARNING: --prefix is not given, defaulting to empty prefix.
         This is probably not what you want! In order to stay compatible
         with regular remote-tracking refs, provide a prefix like
         --prefix=origin/ (remember the trailing slash), which will cause
         the SVN-tracking refs to be placed at refs/remotes/origin/*.
NOTE: In Git v2.0, the default prefix will change from empty to 'origin/'.
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/josm/.git/
Using higher level of URL: http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm => http://svn.openstreetmap.org
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/!svn/rvr/100' path not found: Additional errors:: File not found: revision 100, path '/applications/editors/josm'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories

$ cd josm; git reflog
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

Comment: It looks like it's having a problem finding the repository location using that URL. If the migration was successful, it should have given you output during that command that files were being transferred. What happens when you try `git svn fetch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used wrong option `-s` which tells git-svn to expect standard svn repo layout (trunk, branches/*, tags/*) whereas the repository you try to clone doesn't seem to have such. Try

```
git svn clone http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm
```

instead.